# How to design a layout with a GridView and admob adView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design a layout which will have a gridView and a addView in the bottom,but the addView is showing above gridview items.I want the gridview height will automatically adjust the screen

Here is my code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_image"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/add_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for your `add layout` and define this layout on top, and then define your `GridView` below the `add` layout by using `android:layout_above="@id/ad_layout"`. This will solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_image"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/add_layout" />
 </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/home_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_above="@id/ad_layout" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: but I got one issue,the gridview items are filling bottom to up

Comment: Do you have any other element to add in beetween gridview and addlayout??? You can try with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in GreedView

Comment: Okk try with the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in place of `android:layout_above="@id/ad_layout"`. And tell if it solves your problem.

Comment: if I put android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and android:layout_above="@id/ad_layout" both then its working fine

Comment: Okkk Yes my mistake above is used to make the layout above the declared id. And `android:layout_alignParentTop` is putting that grid on top of the screen.