# Adding Admob into GridView -> AdBanner disappears

Tags: android, gridview, admob

I am trying to add 1 adView for 10 dataitem  into gridview (ex:with 36 data item will show 3 adview).

GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_university"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:verticalSpacing="11dp" />
```

first try with (**uni_listview_ads.xml**) file
but not working and show (Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing) message

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adViewUniver"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Inside  **public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)** method

```
   View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.uni_listview_ads, null);
            AdView ads = (AdView) myView.findViewById(R.id.adViewUniver);

            ads.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            ads.setAdUnitId(getUnitID());

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            ads.loadAd(adRequest);

            return myView;
```

After All Attempts failed i replaced all of them by code

```
View getAd() {
    AdView mAdView;

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    mAdView = new AdView(mContext);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(getUnitID());

    // Create an ad request.
    AdRequest adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Optionally populate the ad request builder.

    layout.addView(mAdView);

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder);

    return layout;
}
```

Here just i put this line inside  **public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)** method

```
return getAd();
```

Result:

**first attempt :** show (Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing) message

**second attempt :** working but adView disappear when i make scrolling down and back to top.

Comment: check this out  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20741847/9287163

Comment: that deferrent from what i want but i found a solution